# Can main and constructor be together in a class in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, program-entry-point

Check The below Code :

```
import Shashwat.TestJava;

public class Main extends TestJava {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        System.out.println("Inside Orignal \"Main\" Method");
        Main m = new Main();
    }

    public void Main() {
        System.out.println("Inside Duplicate Main");
    }
}
```

Now the point is that when I execute the program, This line runs

```
System.out.println("Inside Orignal \"Main\" Method");
```

After which I create a Main class Object using

```
Main = new Main();
```

As far as I have seen this should call the constructor which has to be named 'Main' for the Class is named Main. Now This is what it executes to

```
Inside Orignal "Main" Method
```

But I have created a constructor and it should print text out. So Why is it not printing ? Are Constructors not allowed in a class with a main method ?

Comment: `public  void Main()` is not a constructor. It's a `void` method with no arguments named `Main`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not printing, because you've created a `void`-returning method with a name `Main()`, but in order to be a constructor it should rather be:

```
public Main() {
   System.out.println("Inside Duplicate Main");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a constructor, it's a regular method :

```
public void Main()
{
    System.out.println("Inside Duplicate Main");
}
```

Since your Main class has no constructor, the compiler generates a default constructor and calls it when `Main = new Main();` is executed. That's why you don't see `"Inside Duplicate Main"`.

This is a constructor (note there is no return type) :

```
public Main()
{
    System.out.println("Inside Duplicate Main");
}
```

Remove the `void` from your `Main` method and you'll see that your constructor is called.